# How to detect the changes from textarea by dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom){

    // Create a button programmatically:
    var myButton = new Button({
        disabled:true,
        label: "Click me!",
        onClick: function(){
            // Do something:
            dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
        }
    }, "progButtonNode").startup();

});

require(["dijit/form/Textarea","dijit/registry","dojo/dom" ,"dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"], function(Textarea,registry,dom,on){

    var textarea = new Textarea({
        name: "myarea",
        value: "This is the text area...\n\n\n\n\n\n",
        style: "width:200px;"
    }, "myarea").startup();

    //disalbe the button...
    //registry.byId("progButtonNode").set("disabled",true);

    //test
    dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Good!";

    //add onchange event...
    //var button = registry.byId("progButtonNode");
    alert('hi');


    on(textarea,"change",function(){
        alert('3');
        registry.byId("progButtonNode").set("disabled",false);

    });
});
```

The above is my code.

My requirement is detect the changes once it was made from textarea, and then set the button enable. (the button was disable by default)

I am getting error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can help you if you can create a plnkr.

Comment: @nikkwong Thanks for replying, I figure it out finally. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect changes on widget `Textarea`, use `onChange` when initializing it.

Use `registry.byId()` to get you `Button` widged ans set is property `disabled` to false using method `.set()`;

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/41epfsdd/

Please note I have used `intermediateChanges: true` this allow `onChange` to fire on each keystroke which changes value within the widget `Textarea`.
If you omit it or use `intermediateChanges: false` instead, `onChange` event will only fires when the field is blurred.

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dijit/registry", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, Textarea, registry, dom, on) {

  var myButton = new Button({
    disabled: true,
    label: "Click me!"
  }, "progButtonNode").startup();

  var textarea = new Textarea({
    name: "myarea",
    value: "This is the text area...\n\n\n\n\n\n",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    onChange: function() {
      var progButtonNode = registry.byId('progButtonNode');
      progButtonNode.set('disabled', false);
    }
  }, "myarea").startup();
});
```

Edit:
Regarding your comment on how to apply an event handler on an already generate `Textarea` widget. You can use `dojo/on` example:

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
  on(target, "event", function(e){
    // handle the event
  });
});
```

Example based on your comment:

```
on(this.lastCommentTextArea, 'change', function(event){ 
   // handle the event
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question, what if i have already generate the textarea widget, how could I do that? 
`dojo.connect(this.lastCommentTextArea,'Onchange',function()
        {
               digit.byId("addCommentButton").setAttribute('disabled',false);
        });
 `
this will work, but connect is depreciated, so it is not perfect...

Comment: Use `dojo.on` for this as `dojo.connect` is deprecated. Do something like this- `dojo.on(this.lastCommentTextArea, 'change', function(){ dijit.byId('addCommentButton').setAttribute('disabled', false); }); `

Comment: Yes consider using dojo/on  or using yourWidget.on()

Comment: @HuazheYin Please consider accepting my answer if it help you out to solve your question. If you need any further help we are here to help! :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Himanshu actually I do try this, but I am getting error: I uncaught error: can not find property of on .something like that... Do u know what happen?

Comment: @HuazheYin are you sure you have required module "dojo/on" correctly? Which version of dojo are you using?

Comment: @GibboK I am sure that I include the dojo/on and I am using CDN the latest version..

Comment: Require the `dojo.on` module and then try. Although I don't think that the `require` statement is actually needed if directly using `dojo.on`. And please mention the complete exception that you are getting.

Comment: @GibboK @Himanshu Thanks both of you for answering my question. Just take a look my final solution found it works fine without `connect() `function <br>
`var select = registry.byId('myarea');<br>
 
 select.on('change',function(evt){<br>
  alert('fired');<br>
  registry.byId("progButtonNode").set("disabled",false);<br>
 })`<br>

this works after generate the textarea.